# Storing in annotator.js using store plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, annotations, annotate

I am using store plugin of annotator.js
The problem is I am not able to store the received data(enetered into the comment box of annotatorjs ) at the desired location as JSON.

The code for the plugin is as follows

```
$('#page-container').annotator().annotator('addPlugin', 'Store', {
  urls: {

    prefix: '/editor/uploaded',
    update:'/annotations',

  }
});
```

The output I get in console is

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/editor/uploaded/annotations"
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

Please let me know how the storage can be accomplished.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You are building the object passed as parameter wrong, as "prefix" is not a property inside "urls".
Regarding your example, the right way would be:

```
$('#page-container').annotator().annotator('addPlugin', 'Store', {
  prefix: '/editor/uploaded',
  urls: {
    update:'/annotations'
  }
});
```

Then you need to set up the API on the server side, as required by the plugin.

Personally, I ended up creating my own store plugin, so I could process annotations exactly as I needed. It's not very hard and it's really worth the effort.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your store plugin to get inspiration how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public annotatorFunc(): void {
    const pageUri = function () {
        return {
            beforeAnnotationCreated: function (ann) {
            ann.uri = window.location.href;
            }
        };
    };
    const elem = document.querySelector('pdf-container');

    const app = new annotator.App();
    app.include(annotator.ui.main, {element: elem});
    app.include(annotator.storage.http, {prefix: 'http://localhost:8080/api'});
    app.include(pageUri);

    app.start().then(function () {
        app.annotations.load({uri: window.location.href});
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcolme, try to explain you solution so that people can understand the solution and not just copy paste your answer.